# How to add items to a 2-dimensional array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

How do I push the value of input to `tasks.name` and include a default `status: false` to the `$scope.tasks` array?

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="typeTask">
<button ng-click="updateTasks()">Add task</button>
```

JS (AngularJS)

```
var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);
app1.controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.typeTask = "test";

$scope.tasks = [
    { 
      name: 'Example task 1',
      status: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Example task 2',
      status: true 
    },
    {
      name: 'Example task 3',
      status: false
    }
];

$scope.updateTasks = function() {
    $scope.tasks.push()
};

}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just push it as an object to an `tasks` array

```
$scope.updateTasks = function() {
    $scope.tasks.push({  
      name: $scope.typeTask,
      status: false
    })
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.updateTasks = function() {
    $scope.tasks.push({name:$scope.typeTask, status: false})
};
```